# Android: Settings button removed for Full ScreenActivity

Tags: android

Apparently when you make the activity full screen on android it removed the three dots at the top which I used for my settings.

I currently it set to full screen like the following:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Is there another way I can have my activity fullscreen and still access my inflateable menu?

Comment: the fullscreen setting or theme does not provide for an actionbar, the view that holds your settings menu

Answer (score 0):

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` says "get rid of the action bar". Your overflow (" three dots at the top") was in the action bar.

Either:

- Get rid of `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`, or
- Create your own menu system, as part of the UI of the activity, rather than relying upon the action bar overflow